# NSUserDefaults will not load after leaving app

Tags: objective-c, ios, integer, nsuserdefaults

I set up multiple NSUserDefaults in my app that work for the most part.  The NSUserDefaults are called from one ViewController and implemented at another (such as in a game with a level select).  This seems to work well, until the user presses the back button on the level select screen.  When they try to go back to the level select viewController, the NSUserDefaults are not loaded onto the screen.
Here is my code:

LevelSelectViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{       
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)Level1DidFinish:(Level1 *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger rank = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"levelRank"];
    {
        if (rank == 1) {
            button2.hidden = NO;

        }
    }
}
```

Level1ViewController:

```
{            
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"levelRank"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is you are creating an instance of `userDefaults`, but are not setting any values. So calling **`synchronize`** here is actually doing nothing:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

After you set a your `Integer`, then you need to call `synchronize`:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"easyRank"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: So then would I put anything in the viewDidLoad or just leave it blank?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what I needed to do.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [userDefaults synchronize] after setting a value for a key. The automatic synchronization happens quite rarely, so in this case, while one completes a level, the sync won't have yet happened.

So modify your code like this:

Level1ViewController:

```
{            
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"easyRank"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting values for two different keys. What are you expecting to happen?

Either `Level1ViewController` needs to set a value for `levelRank` or `LevelSelectViewController` needs to read the value for the `easyRank` key.

Comment: Sorry, the levelRank and the easyRank were supposed to be the same.  I was trying to get it more generic.  It should be fixed now